# How to judge http proxy

Tags: http, proxy

everyone! I have a list of http proxy servers, some of then may stop running http proxy process. Of course, there are two cases: the port is not listened any more; and the port may be listened for another service. I have to write a program to judge if a given server is still running http proxy. How can I do that? If I can connect to a port, how can I judge whether it provides http proxy service or not? Is there protocol relative thing I can employ?

Answer (score 0):

Most proxy servers use port numbers like 8080, which are not assigned to any other services. In those cases, if you can connect, it is usually safe to assume it is still a proxy.

In the case that the proxy server uses a standard port like 80, you may want to make a single request to a known host on the internet. That way you can know that it is still forwarding requests to the outside.

If you're trying to see what services are available on any given server or port, something like [nmap](http://nmap.org/) may be useful. nmap can usually identify the type of service running on any given port.

**IMPORTANT: Running a full port scan on a remote host is (almost always) illegal unless you have written permission from the owner of that host. Sometimes it is illegal even if you have written permission**.

Scanning one targeted port using nmap is probably okay.